# How to include tools namespace in a style xml

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I want to be able to use

```
tools:text="Text"
```

in a style.xml file, this way don't duplicate tools:text in all my layout that are using the style.

I've already tried:

```
<item name="text">@string/text</item>
```

but when is present the editor doesn't show the text.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 16):

According to the documentation: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes.html#design-time_view_attributes

> `tools:` instead of `android:`
>
> *Intended for:* `<View>`
>
> *Used by: Android Studio layout editor*

Unfortunately, this means you can't use `tools:text` inside a `<style>` element.

Comment: The documentation states "These are attributes which are used when the layout is rendered in the tool, but have no impact on the runtime." So its my opinion, anyway, that they don't belong in styles, as they are stripped away at build time.